# Drawing Between Two Points on an Android Emulator in Java

Tags: java, android, drawing

Given two points on an emulator (x and y values for both coordinates), how do I draw a line connecting them?

I have already retrieved the two coordinates like this...

```
//imports not included
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(iv.getLayoutParams());
float fx = event.getX();
float fy = event.getY();
int x = (int)fx;
int y = (int)fy;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Canvas.drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)`
method to draw a straight line between two points using X, Y coordinates like the following Code Snippet.

> Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
>
> Paint paint = new Paint();
>
> paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
>
> paint.setColor(Color.Black);
>
> paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
>
> paint.setAntiAlias(true);
>
> Canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);